# Know increased percentage

Tags: percentages

I have to percentages `15%`and `85%`in total `100%`:

When I want to change the `15%` to `35%` i calculate:

```
35 / 15 = 2.3333333
```

Next I calculate: `15 * 2.3333 = 35`

**Now what I want to know if:**

By only knowing the percentage `233.3333%` with that I had to multiplicate my `15%` I can guess the percentage I have to duplicate with `35%` to end with in total `100%`:

Means:

I only know `35%` and `233.3333%`
   and now I want to know:

```
 35 * ?? =
```

Thanks!!

Comment: $25*2.333$ is not 35.

Comment: @John Smith Please elaborate a little more what do you really need.

Comment: Sorry! I corrected it!

Comment: @John Smith Do you want to calculate back 15% given both 35% and 2.333333? You ought to divide 35 by 2.3333333

Comment: When I know that I increased some percentage by `233.33%` to come to `30%` Can I know from that how much percentage I have decrease the other part to come to 100% ?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura did you see my comment?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura ho can I come back from 35 to 15 wich percentag is ist?

Comment: @John Smith Just divide the number by 2.3333333, which will yield 15% back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a percentage by which you increase a number, and wants to go back to the original number by multiplying a new percentage, right? This new percentage is equal to the inverse of the one you firstly used to increase the number,
$$new\space percentage=\frac{1}{233.3333\text{%}}=\frac{1}{2.333333}=42.86\text{%}$$